# Migrating a 20GB website to Netfirms .. Would like solutions

Tags: ftp

I am a non-profit who is transferring my site to Netfirms and their "plus" shared hosting plan. All they give me is FTP access, and a silly decompressor webapp called "Archive Gateway" that can decompress `.tar`, `.zip`, `.gz` and `.z`.

**Netfirms expects me to upload my whole site by FTP.**

**I'm trying to avoid uploading 20GBs from my puny residential connection.**

Netfirms doesn't give me SSH, so running `wget`, `split`, `cat` or `ftp` from netfirms is not possible.

My old host gives me SSH access, and I ran `ftp` there to send my `site-backup.tar` to NetFirms, but this SSH cuts me off when it senses I'm away from the console for several minutes. Only 800MB gets transferred.

I tried using a .PHP script in Netfirms to retrieve `site.backup.tar` from the old host but this script times out.

- Can tar create split archives of around 500MB each with no files split in between?
- Can you suggest how I can transfer 20GB of site data to Netfirms?

In the meantime, I will try to figure out how to archive my 20GB site into several 500MB `tar`s.

Comment: 20GB of web content is a lot of content. Considering your level of expertise and content size, are you sure that it's worth it moving to a service with such limitations? An operation like this would require the servers admins involvement.

Comment: If you have SSH access, read `man nohup`

Comment: @danlefree: `ftp` requires interactive input, I'm afraid, i.e., `cat script | ftp` doesn't work, so sorry `nohup` doesn't work on it either. :(

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file named `ftp_commands` in the same directory as your large archive file.

The contents of the file should resemble the following:

```
open example.com
user username p@ssword
binary
put archive_file.tar.gz
```

Save the file and run `nohup ftp -ni < ftp_commands &`

Answer (score 0):

1. Initiate ssh-session with keep-alive settings on
2. Long time ago child processes was not **not** terminated, when I close ssh by hand and later return back

You can also try to use FXP (FTP server-to-server transfer) is SRC-server support this extension